# id field is not int and CakePHP

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a database table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass_word` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `privilege` char(1) DEFAULT 'C',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1256;
```

**You may notice that** the `id` field is not `int`. It is `varchar`. The problem here, when I try to bake this table into model, controller and use scaffolding, I got the following screen shot with new user view:

[image]

You should notice that there is no id field in which I want to enter it as varchar. Also setting validation to the id to be alphanumeric and notempty, prevents the record to be added.

Is there any solution for this without need to change the table structure?

Comment: I'd imagine that the primary key would be excluded from Cake's scaffolding by default, regardless of its field type.

Comment: This was an old application, I decided to make the user id to work as primary key. It makes more better (quicker) visual representation to identify the user.

Comment: Yeah, but what I'm saying is that if it's not the primary key, it will probably show up in your scaffolded form.

Comment: @scrowler Even when I bake views and stop scaffolding then edit add view `echo $this->Form->input('id');` the form helper does not render input field for it.

Comment: No, it won't because it's the primary key which should never be user editable

Comment: Could I understand that I have to alter my table structure to continue with CakePHP at this project?

Comment: I think so, just make the id `int(15)` with auto_increment...

Comment: I suggest you to add another int field with auto_increment (key int(11) auto_increment, for instance) and set primary key to it in your model file.(public $primaryKey = 'key';). Then you won't bother modifying parameters in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this visible, in your add view, add this line:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'text'));
```

However I wouldn't make the primary key editable, this will lead to all sorts of problems down the track.  What happens if you have foreign keys that are linked to this record, and then the administrator changes the primary key?  Bad news.

I'd make the primary key an integer auto-increment field, and then have another field for user_code or similar.  This will let you still have a user key that is editable, which won't affect your relations.